# Package app in Shoes4

Tags: ruby, shoes

I used Shoes4 to make a GUI for my ruby app. Now I'm packaging this app, but something's wrong.

I followed this https://github.com/shoes/shoes4 to package. 
'rake gem' gave me:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081:in `load'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `eval'
/Users/xxxxxxx/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.13/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:15:in `(root)'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

'gem install pkg/shoes-4.0.0.pre1.gem' gave me:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pkg/shoes-4.0.0.pre1.gem' (>= 0) in any repository
```

'bin/shoes -p swt:app path/to/directory-of/your-shoes-app.rb' still packaged my app (I coded in a Mac). However, the app won't run on Macs and it said 'quit unexpectedly'. The funny thing is that the app runs well in a Windows 7.

Have I done something wrong? How am I supposed to make the app work on Macs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install Shoes?

Answer (score 0):

Packaging is still a baby and sadly breaks some times.

We fixed a couple of packaging bugs (especially some for Mac) in the last months. I'd welcome you to try again fresh from master of [shoes](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4).

If the problem persists, please [open an issue over at Shoes4](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues/new) so we can tackle it appropriately :)